# Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object " error while running update query

Tags: sql, ms-access, sharepoint

I am very new to access and Microsoft technologies. So this might be a very silly question but  I have already spent a couple of days on this issue.

I have linked a share point list with an access database and try to run an update query like below to update two date fields.

```
UPDATE [Table_Name] 
SET [Table_Name].Start = [Table_Name].[Start]+168,
    [Table_Name].[End] = [END]+168;
```

Every time this is giving below error,

***The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object ''. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If '' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.***

I have full access on this list and able to run select queries but update queries are giving this error, I have tried to run a basic update query and that also gives the same error.

I have also tried to delete the link and create again but no luck.

Please help me to resolve this issue...any pointer is highly appreciated.

regards,

Vaibhav

Comment: You're bracketing and specifying table name inconsistently. While `Start` is not a keyword in Access SQL, it is in different dialects. Try bracketing that, and specifying the tablename for the second `End`.

Comment: Thanks Erik, I have tried all permutation and combinations of Bracketing Table name and column name (I am that desperate)...but it is not working.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm at a loss as well. Afaik if the list is updateable in Access (you can modify it when you open it as a table) and that table name is the same as the name of the table name in Access, this should just work.

Comment: I also thought so..but sadly it is not how access is behaving. Just out of curiosity, Is there any special kind of setting we require..which enable us to edit list in access. I have edited another list in the same site using this process...so I thought by default I can edit any list in Access.

Comment: Eh... SharePoint lists generally are just updateable if you have the right privileges, and if the list has a unique identifier (primary key). See [Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-or-link-to-data-in-a-sharepoint-list-65bf7b03-74bf-445c-959a-24b7a401ddee) for a general how to link.

Comment: Hey @VaibhavDwivedi.. were you able to solve the issue?